# Accessing private package version info using $npm_package_ notation

Tags: javascript, npm

Npm has a handy prefix to access package information from the `package.json` for example I can extract the react version using `$npm_package_dependencies_react` which will return me the current version for react listed in the `package.json` file.

My question is, how can I access the information using the same mechanic for packages that are listed with an `@` prefix, such as, `@types/react`. I have tried escaping the special characters to no avail, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two underscores `__` for the `@` and one underscore `_` for the slash `/`.

For instance, for `@types/react` use the following notation:

```
$npm_package_dependencies__types_react
```

**Notes:**

- If you `cd` to your project directory and then run the following command it will list all available environment variables:

  ```
  npm run env
  ```
- On windows, npm utilizes *cmd.exe* as the default shell. In which case the environment variables are accessed using the `%...%` syntax instead of a dollar `$` prefix. For example:

  ```
  %npm_package_dependencies__types_react%
  ```
- For cross-platform compatibility consider utilizing [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var).

Comment: The double underscore is what I was after and thanks for the `npm run env` tip!